# How to give child component control over react hook in root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an application that adds GitHub users to a list.  When I put input in the form, a user is returned and added to the list.  I want the user to be added to the list only if I click on the user when it shows up after the resource request.  Specifically, what I want is to have a click event in the child component trigger the root component’s triggering of the hook, to add the new element to the list.

Root component,

```
const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([])

  const addNewCard = cardInfo => {
    console.log("addNewCard called ...")
    setCards([cardInfo, ...cards])
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form onSubmit={addNewCard}/>
      <CardsList cards={cards} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Form component,

```
const Form = props => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

    const chooseUser = (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    } 

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.persist();
        console.log("FETCHING ...")
        fetch(`http://localhost:3666/api/users/${username}`, {
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(resp => {
            console.log("RESULT: ", resp)
            props.onSubmit(resp)
            setUsername('')
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const checkStatus = response => {
        console.log(response.status)
        const status = response.status
        if (status >= 200 && status <= 399) return response
        else console.log("No results ...")
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Gitbub username"
                value={username}
                required
                onChange={chooseUser}
                onKeyUp={debounce(handleSubmit, 1000)}
            />
            <button type="submit">Add card</button>
        </form>
    )
}
export default Form;
```

List component,

```
const CardsList = props => {

    return (
        <div>
            {props.cards.map(card => (
                <Card key={card.html_url} {... card} 
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardsList
```

and the Card Component,

```
const Card = props => {

    const [selected, selectCard] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div style={{margin: '1em'}}>
            <img alt="avatar" src={props.avatar_url} style={{width: '70px'}} />
            <div>
                <div style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}><a href={props.html_url}>{props.name}</a></div>
                <div>{props.blog}</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

Right now, my Form component has all the control.  How can I give control over the `addNewCard` method in App to the Card child component?

Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to create a removeCard method in App which is fired if the click event you want controlling `addNewCard` doesn't happen.

```
// App.js
...
const removeCard = username => {
    console.log("Tried to remove card ....", username)
    setCards([...cards.filter(card => card.name != username)])
  }
```

Then you pass both removeCard and addNewCard to CardList.

```
// App.js
...
  <CardsList remove={removeCard} cards={cards} add={addNewCard}/>
```

Go ahead and pass those methods on to Card in CardsList. You will also want some prop on card assigned to a boolean, like, "selected".

```
// CardsList.js
 return (
        <div>
            {props.cards.map(card => (
                <Card key={card.html_url} {... card} 
                remove={handleClick} 
                add={props.add}
                selected={false}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
```

Set up your hook and click event in the child Card component,

```
// Card.js
...
const [selected, selectCard] = useState(false)
...
```

and configure your events to trigger the hook and use the state.

```
// Card.js
...

    return (
        <div style={{margin: '1em', opacity: selected ? '1' : '0.5'}}
            onMouseLeave={() => selected ? null : props.remove(props.name)}
            onClick={() => selectCard(true)}
        >
...
```

This doesn't really shift control of `addNewCard` from Form to Card, but it ultimately forces the UI to follow the state of the Card component.